# How to Handle 'Message From Webpage' pop-up in Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, popup, watir

Can anyone tell me how to handle the pop-up in Watir? I have tried all the ways that have been mentioned in the following site:

```
http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/
```

I have also gone through the other questions that have been mentioned on StackOverflow but they are not working either.

it's a pop-up with the title "Message from webpage"

I proceeded in the following way: I manually process through the command prompt, when I hit the button then the 'Message from Webpage' pops-up and I am unable to process any commands through the command prompt.

See the below image:

[image]

Comment: for your info these is getting executed on IE-8

Comment: are you doing require 'watir-webdriver' or 'watir' ?

Comment: What actually happens when you try the solutions mentioned on the Watir-Webdriver page - ie what does "not working either" mean? Is there an exception?

Comment: @Titus requiring watir.......

Comment: In my script I have mention the command that has been specifed in watir-webdriver page,when the pop-up pops-up,in command line the next staement is not getting executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now when you require 'watir' the api is implemented differently for Internet Explorer than it is for other browsers.

You can either use:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
```

or you can specify:

```
require 'watir'
Watir.driver = :webdriver
```

This is something that you shouldn't have to do, and it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I did the same I am unable to close the pop-up window I tried it manually through the "CMD" prompt it actually get closed when I require watir-weebdriver but unable to do when I require 'watir' can u suggest how to close using "Watir" without switching to watir-webdriver

Comment: I'm confused, you started by referencing the watir-webdriver documentation. Webdriver is the future of browser automation, and will be implemented around the forthcoming w3c specification. 

The watir-classic implementation is being maintained by Justin Ko, so if you have to use it for some reason, he's the person to help figure out your issue.